# Custom sorting in JavaScript homework question

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Write a function named `sort_by_average_rating` that takes a list/array of key-value stores as a parameter where each key-value store has keys `ratings`, `budget`, and `box_office` where `budget` and `box_office` are integers and ratings is a list of integers. Sort the input based on the average of the values in `ratings`.

I tried adding everything within a for loop when the key is equal to `["ratings"]` then after that, I average the results from the two for loops. Lastly, I used a separate function to sort everything.

```
function key(a,b){
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    tol1 += a[i]["ratings"];  

  for(var x = 0; x < b.length; x++) {
    tol2 += b[x]["ratings"];
    }
    var average = (tol1/tol2);
  }
  return average;
}

function key(x,y){
  if (x[key] < x[key]) { return -1; }
  if (y[key] > y[key]) { return 1; }
  return 0;
 }

function sort_by_average_rating(b){
  b.sort(key)
 }
```

**Result:**

```
[
    {'box_office': 12574015, 'budget': 3986053.18, 'ratings': [8, 7, 1]}, 
    {'box_office': 44855251, 'budget': 3301717.62, 'ratings': [7, 1, 1]}, 
    {'box_office': 36625133, 'budget': 8678591, 'ratings': [7, 6, 2, 8]}, 
    {'box_office': 48397691, 'budget': 15916122.88, 'ratings': [7, 3, 8, 8, 6, 8]}, 
    {'box_office': 43344800, 'budget': 4373679.25, 'ratings': [1, 1, 7, 4]}
]
```

**Expected:**

```
[
    {'box_office': 44855251, 'budget': 3301717.62, 'ratings': [7, 1, 1]}, 
    {'box_office': 43344800, 'budget': 4373679.25, 'ratings': [1, 1, 7, 4]}, 
    {'box_office': 12574015, 'budget': 3986053.18, 'ratings': [8, 7, 1]}, 
    {'box_office': 36625133, 'budget': 8678591.0, 'ratings': [7, 6, 2, 8]}, 
    {'box_office': 48397691, 'budget': 15916122.88, 'ratings': [7, 3, 8, 8, 6, 8]}
]
```

Comment: You have two `function key()`. Only the second definition is used, the first one is overwritten. Actually, that's just the tip of the iceberg... `key` inside the function is still referring to the function itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a function that return the `average` of a `ratings` array, we going to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this one. Then you can use this new function with the built-in [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to generate your desired result:

```js
const input = [
  {'box_office': 12574015, 'budget': 3986053.18, 'ratings': [8, 7, 1]},
  {'box_office': 44855251, 'budget': 3301717.62, 'ratings': [7, 1, 1]},
  {'box_office': 36625133, 'budget': 8678591, 'ratings': [7, 6, 2, 8]},
  {'box_office': 48397691, 'budget': 15916122.88, 'ratings': [7, 3, 8, 8, 6, 8]},
  {'box_office': 43344800, 'budget': 4373679.25, 'ratings': [1, 1, 7, 4]}
];

const getAverage = (arr) =>
{
    return (Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length > 0) ?
           arr.reduce((acc, n) => acc + n) / arr.length :
           0;
};

input.sort((a, b) => getAverage(a.ratings) - getAverage(b.ratings));
console.log(input);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

To avoid **mutation** of the original data, use:

```
let sorted = input.slice().sort((a, b) => getAverage(a.ratings) - getAverage(b.ratings));
```

Comment: Would help to pass an initial value of `0` to `reduce()` in case there are no ratings... though then the result would be `NaN`. 0/0 is indeterminate.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for the feedback, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use a different approach ([sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map)) by taking the averages in an array and another array for the indices, sort the indices array and map the objects by taking the indices.

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;

var array = [{ box_office: 12574015, budget: 3986053.18, ratings: [8, 7, 1] }, { box_office: 44855251, budget: 3301717.62, ratings: [7, 1, 1] }, { box_office: 36625133, budget: 8678591, ratings: [7, 6, 2, 8] }, { box_office: 48397691, budget: 15916122.88, ratings: [7, 3, 8, 8, 6, 8] }, { box_office: 43344800, budget: 4373679.25, ratings: [1, 1, 7, 4] }],
    averages = array.map(({ ratings }) => ratings.reduce(add, 0) / ratings.length),
    indices = [...averages.keys()].sort((i, j) => averages[i] - averages[j]),
    result = indices.map(i => array[i]);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

1) you should initialize your variables before using them (e.g. `tol1`

2) you should avoid repeating function names (e.g. `key`)

3) you should name your variables and functions something meaningful (e.g. 'a', 'b', 'key', 'x', 'y') mean nothing.

```js
let movies = [
  {'box_office': 12574015, 'budget': 3986053.18, 'ratings': [8, 7, 1]},
  {'box_office': 44855251, 'budget': 3301717.62, 'ratings': [7, 1, 1]},
  {'box_office': 36625133, 'budget': 8678591, 'ratings': [7, 6, 2, 8]},
  {'box_office': 48397691, 'budget': 15916122.88, 'ratings': [7, 3, 8, 8, 6, 8]},
  {'box_office': 43344800, 'budget': 4373679.25, 'ratings': [1, 1, 7, 4]}
];

let averageRating = movie => 
    movie.ratings.reduce((rating, sum) => rating + sum, 0) / movie.ratings.length;

let sortedMovies = movies.sort((movie1, movie2) => averageRating(movie1) - averageRating(movie2));

console.log(sortedMovies);
```